# vue component styling issue

Tags: css, scope, vue-component

I have imported some css files in my component.

```
<template>    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnglobal.immowelt.org/global-assets/4.0.0/fonts/fontello.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnglobal.immowelt.org/global-assets/4.0.0/legacy/0/base.css">
...
<template>
```

The thing is I want this styles to apply on this component.
They affects on other parent and sibling templates.
Is it possible to enable this to be applied on one template's elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing .vue single file components you can use this:

```
<style scoped src="./something.css">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to import your CSS in  component with

```
<style scoped>
@import url("https://cdnglobal.immowelt.org/global-assets/4.0.0/legacy/0/base.css")
@import url("https://cdnglobal.immowelt.org/global-assets/4.0.0/fonts/fontello.css")
...your CSS...
</style>
```

I use Fontello too with Vuejs, are you trying to use your own icons?

Comment: Yeah, frankly I have ever used this method.